# Get specific row from table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retrieve data from specific rows in a table based on check box selection done by the user.

For this, I have found two methods `eq(rowIndex)` and `nth-child(rowIndex)`. However,it works only when given an absolute values and not when its dynamic.

Have tried the following but no luck on this:

```
function getData()
 {
    var chkArr = document.getElementsByName('checkbox');
    var checkedRecord = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<chkArr.length; i++)
    {   
    if(chkArr[i].checked)
    {
              checkedRecord = i;
              $('#summaryTable > tbody  > tr').eq('#checkedRecord').children('td').each(function(j)
            //checkedRecord is the row index here
             {
             //fetch values from td
             }); 
          }
      }  
 }
```

Here's how my html looks

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="text1"></td>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="opt1">Orange</option>
            <option value="opt2">Green</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: can you please provide an example with also the table code? www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you post your HTML so we can see what and where '#checkedRecord' is.

Comment: Remove last `>` in selector

Comment: `eq()` takes a number, not a selector.

Comment: fetch values from which `td`?

Comment: @DKM Done.That was a typo!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Alright. How should it be in this case then?

Comment: We really can't help you without seeing the HTML as well, could you post it?

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
$('#summaryTable > tbody  >  tr').eq(i).children('td')
    .each(function() { ... });
```

The argument to `eq` must be a number.

There's also no need for the `checkedRecord` variable, it's the same as `i`.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method need integer value as parameter, but you pass a selector syntax to this method. Look at your code at line:

```
$('#summaryTable > tbody  > tr').eq('#checkedRecord')....
```

You have define `checkedRecord` variable above as `var checkedRecord = 0;`. So you need to modify that line to become:

```
$('#summaryTable > tbody  > tr').eq(checkedRecord)....
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var gridRows = $("#myTable tbody tr");
var qnt = gridRows[i].cells[2].childNodes[0].value;
```

and if you want all rows data so use this function

```
function GridCount() {
        var grid = $("#myTable tbody");
        var gridRows = $("#myTable tbody tr");
        var gridfootRows = $("#myTable tfoot tr");
        var subTotal = 0;
        var Id;
        var Name;
        for (var i = 0; i < gridRows.length; i++) {
            if (isFireFox()) {
                Id = gridRows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
                Name = gridRows[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            }
            else {
                Id = gridRows[i].cells[0].innerText;
                Name = gridRows[i].cells[0].innerText;
            }
            var qnt = gridRows[i].cells[2].childNodes[0].value;
            var price = gridRows[i].cells[3].childNodes[0].value;
            var total = parseFloat(price * qnt).toFixed(2);
            gridRows[i].cells[4].childNodes[0].innerHTML = total;
            subTotal = parseFloat(subTotal) + parseFloat(total);
        }

}
function isFireFox() {
   return navigator.appName == "Netscape";
}
```

Comment: why the mix of jquery and plain javascript?

Comment: problem in browser comparability so i am using this.

Comment: jQuery handles browser compatibility for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for, but it seems you want to find the values of selects found in rows that correspond by index to checked checkboxes. This will allow you do do that:

```
function getData() {
    var rows = $('#summaryTable > tbody  > tr'), //cache rows for performance
        values = []; //array of values to return

    //iterate through all checkboxes
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (i) { 
        if(this.checked) {
            //if checkbox is checked, find select and get value, then add to values array
            values.push(rows.eq(i).find('select').val()); 
        }
    });

    return values;
}
```